# ASP.NET C# to VB conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I have a Web Application that I'm trying to update. I am required to code using Visual Basic, yet the old version has some C# code that's giving me a hard time to translate into VB. I'd appreciate any help you can give me thanks. :)

```
clsSeguridad oseg = new clsSeguridad();
oseg.DatosLogin += new EventHandler<clsSeguridad.DatosLoginEventArgs>(oseg_DatosLogin);
```

The first line is easy to translate. Basically, this is what's going on:
cslSeguridad is a custom class that contains many methods to validate a user Login. In order to login, you must first create the object and then add the EventHandler that will be invoked later on in the method. That's the problem for me... I can't seem to be able to add a new Handler... Visual Studio suggests that I use a RaiseEvent, yet I am unsure that that's what I am supposed to do since I didn't write up the original code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: AddHandler oseg.DatosLogin, AddressOf oseg_DatosLogin

Comment: You probably have Web Site project, where VB can live next to C#. In web application you can use only one language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.NET, you would use:

```
AddHandler oseg.DatosLogin, New EventHandler(Of clsSeguridad.DatosLoginEventArgs)(oseg_DatosLogin)
```

The [AddHandler statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) is used to attach a function or subroutine to an event.

For future reference, you can use one of the numerous online tools available to convert code between C# and VB. Matt Wilko suggests http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

Comment: Have you tried converting the OPs code using the tool you suggested? It fails to convert it correctly. This tool works a bit better:- http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

Comment: You need an 'AddressOf' there: AddHandler oseg.DatosLogin, AddressOf oseg_DatosLogin

Comment: @DaveDoknjas No you don't. AddressOf is required when you're trying to get a delegate from a compile time declared procedure. `New EventHandler` already returns a delegate object, so you don't need AddressOf.

Comment: If you're using the long-form AddHandler as you are, and if 'oseg_DatosLogin' is a procedure, then your argument for the EventHandler constructor call should be "AddressOf oseg_DatosLogin".

Answer (score 1):

I have been know to use .Net reflector to translate code between C# and VB. You can also pick Delphi, F#, IL C++ and Oxygene as language targets. If you are using a debug assembly, the disassembled code snippets are usually pretty close to what you would write by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1 . Hard coded handling

declare your class member _member `WithEvents` and later declate a method as

```
`private sub MySub() Handles _member.Event`
```

2 .  More dynamic way

Somewhere in code use

```
AddHandler _member.Event, addressOf (handling_sub)
```

Don't forget to use `RemoveHandler` or ... memory leaks